# How can I return the values with the same length in a dictionary?

Tags: python

Currently, I have the following dictionary, with a key, and values of type dictionary as well:

```
db = {
    'john'  : {'a': 13, 'b': 64, 'c': 43},
    'eric'  : {'a': 63, 'b': 12},
    'kek'   : {'a': 43, 'b': 37, 'c': 83, 'd': 87},
    'rick'  : {'a': 77, 'b': 66, 'c': 44},
    'alex'  : {'a': 44, 'b': 99, 'c': 22}
}
```

How can I return a set of all the keys with the same number of items in the value part? In the dictionary above, the keys: `john`, `rick`, `alex` all have the same amount of keys. So the output would include these.

**Expected Output:**

```
same = {john, rick, alex}
```

---

Here is my code so far, i'm not sure how to store the current length:

```
db = {
    'john': {'a': 13, 'b': 64, 'c': 43},
    'eric': {'a': 63, 'b': 12},
    'kek': {'a': 43, 'b': 37, 'c': 83, 'd': 87},
    'rick': {'a': 77, 'b': 66, 'c': 44},
    'alex': {'a': 44, 'b': 99, 'c': 22}
}

def maximum(db):
    same = {}
    for key, value in db.items():
        for values in value:
            if len(values) == 'something':
                pass

maximum(db)
```

Comment: The question is ambiguous. There can be many such sets. Do you mean the return value should be the be set containing maximum elements?

Comment: What of there  values corresponding to key `64` and `91` are also of same length?

Comment: Please give an answer to @VigneshBayariR. 's comment as the question is unclear

Comment: I have edited the post, I think it should be more clearer with names. What I mean't to say is to create a new set, then return the keys that have the same amount of keys in the values.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, You can find your desires  in the result:

```
from itertools import groupby

result = []
for i,j in groupby(sorted(db.items(), key = lambda x:len(x[1])), lambda x:len(x[1])):
    result.append({i:[k[0] for k in j]})
```

then the result will be:

```
[{2: ['eric']}, {3: ['john', 'rick', 'alex']}, {4: ['kek']}]
```

`keys` are the `len` of items and `values` are those which has that length.

Answer (score 0):

I have your output when I enter the following code:

```
def maximum(db):
    for key, value in db.items():
        if len(value) == 3:
            print(key)

maximum(db)
```

Instead of `print()` enter whatever suits your needs of course.

Comment: This is okay, but it doesn't necessary help because the dictionary values could be different length and it is not always 3.

Comment: Ah, so you want all keys for all length basically? So you get a dictionary where the key is the length and the values are your keys?

Answer (score 0):

Since OP says thats he requires the `keys` which have `values` of the same length, so that length must be the most frequent occuring length (ofcourse this is an assumption, but OP has not clarified that. There could be, for instance two sets ot `values`, having length either 2 or 3, so we should output `keys` corresponding to which value lengths? 2 or 3?)

```
db = {'john': {'a': 13, 'b': 64, 'c': 43}, 
      'eric': {'a': 63, 'b': 12}, 
      'kek': {'a': 43, 'b': 37, 'c': 83, 'd': 87}, 
      'rick': {'a': 77, 'b': 66, 'c': 44}, 
      'alex': {'a': 44, 'b': 99, 'c': 22} }

from collections import Counter
elem_len = [len(r) for k,r in db.items()]
c = Counter(elem_len)
most_common_length = c.most_common(1)[0][0]
print(most_common_length)
    3

elements = [k for k,r in db.items() if len(r)==most_common_length]
print(elements)
    ['john', 'rick', 'alex']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db = {51: {'a': 13, 'b': 64, 'c': 43}, 64: {'a': 63, 'b': 12}, 87: {'a': 43, 'b': 37, 'c': 83, 'd': 87}, 91: {'a': 77, 'b': 66, 'c': 44}, 99: {'a': 44, 'b': 99, 'c': 22} }

def maximum(db):
    count_map = {}
    for key, value in db.items():
        if len(value.keys()) in count_map.keys():
            count_map[len(value.keys())].append(key)
            continue

        count_map[len(value.keys())] = [key,]

    countwise_list = list(count_map.values())
    countwise_list.sort(key=(lambda x: len(x)), reverse=True)

    return countwise_list[0]
```